# Significato di "serrare in una morsa" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La mennulara*, di Simonetta Agnello Hornby, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> “Presidente, lei sa che la mafia è sotto pressione nelle grandi città. La magistratura potrebbe **serrarla in una morsa**. E allora, in vista della stangata, ecco che si ritrae nei piccoli centri, per poi tornare ad attaccare.”

Sul [dizionario De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/morsa) ho trovato che l'espressione "serrare in una morsa" fa riferimento a una "stretta violenta delle mani o delle dita", ma è chiaro che nel brano precedente si usa in senso figurato. Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa? Potrebbe essere "mettere in difficoltà"?

Un'altra domanda: sapreste dirmi se
questo uso figurato ha una certa diffusione? O si tratterebbe invece di un'invenzione dell'autrice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

È una similitudine. Come con la morsa (lo strumento da lavoro) si bloccano saldamente i pezzi durante la lavorazione, così la magistratura renderebbe completamente **inoperativa** la mafia nelle città, **bloccandone** ogni attività. L'espressione significa quindi molto più che "mettere in difficoltà". La mafia sarebbe completamente **immobilizzata**.

Espressioni simili, ma meno forti, possono essere "legare le mani", "legare mani e piedi".

Anche nel significato "stretta violenta delle mani o delle dita" si fa uso di una similitudine paragonando le mani o le dita letterali alle ganasce della morsa.

La morsa è usata con una certa frequenza in questo tipo di similitudini, espressioni comparative o linguaggio figurato, con diverse accezioni, come indicato nel [Vocabolario Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/morsa/). Oltre al verbo serrare, vengono utilizzati anche altri verbi come stringere o chiudere.